# How to enforce unique field in Google Cloud Endpoints API (GAE)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, jdo

I have a custom user object in my Google Cloud Endpoints API:

```
public class User {

   @PrimaryKey
   @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
   private Long id; // <- This is unique by default because of @PrimaryKey

   @Persistent
   private String username; // <- How to make this unique as well

   ...
}
```

What would be the best way of enforcing an arbitrary field to be unique? Should I just, in my insert method, query for a user with the given username to check if it already exists?

I have looked at answers given in [older posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563070/how-to-enforce-unique-field-value-in-java-google-app-engine), but was wondering if anything has changed since then.

Comment: There was no change and there probably won't ever be one since unique restrictions on properties don't work in the datastore. It's simply not built that way. It's easy enough though to create a workaround for this with an additional table which holds the usernames as keys. You can probably even write a Java annotation that checks this.

Comment: @konqi Ok, thanks. I'll probably try creating an additional table for unique usernames then.

Comment: No idea what is this "EndPoints", but JDO has clear documentation on how to DEFINE a unique constraint, http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jdo/orm/constraints.html#unique

Comment: @NeilStockton from what I understand, a lot of JDO features are not supported in GAE because of limitations in the underlying datastore.

Comment: well if the underlying datastore doesn't support something as basic as unique columns (does it? have you checked?) then how do you expect this to be enforced ? client side?

Comment: @NeilStockton I will be doing what is described in the accepted answer in the SO post I linked to in my question